# Custom color highlighting for Pylance in VS Code: defined variables in white, undefined variables in red

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I am using Pylance in VS Code (Dark Theme), writing Python 3.9.
When semantic highlighting is enabled, well defined variables are colored in cyan and when I use a variable that is not defined (and will yield error when running the code) it is colored in white.

I want to change this such that a well defined variable will be colored in white and undefined variable will be colored in red (the color of error).

I know I need to edit the `settings.json` but I didn't find what I am looking for in the documentation below.

References: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release#semantic-highlighting

**Added in edited:**
With the code below (by @JialeDu) this is the result:
[image]

Updated test code:

```
# test
import numpy as np
import os.path as osp

def f(x):
    return 6*x

fx = f(x=1)
fbad = f(x=bad)

x = 1
y = 2 + x + z

a, b = 1, 2

class test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.x1 = 1
        self.x2 = 2

ins1 = test()
print(ins1.x1)
```

[image: Example with new code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following configuration may be useful to you

```json
// settings.json file
{
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations":{
        "[Default Dark+]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "meta.function-call.arguments.python, source.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#FF0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "scope": "variable.other.readwrite",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#ffffff"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "scope": "punctuation.separator.arguments.python, punctuation.section.function.begin.python,punctuation.separator.parameters.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#D4D4D4"
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
}
```

looks like this on my computer

[image]

*Note that the above configuration may cause other unexpected changes. Because scopes of changing the color might work in some other places as well.*

Comment: Thank you. I added this code snippet and it highlights undefined variable in red only when it is an argument of a function, and not in general code block. I attach a photo in my question (edit).

Comment: Please see the updated answer. But let me just say that, as mentioned in my answer, these changes are likely to bring some other unanticipated changes. Because it's impossible for me to test all the code you've come across, and the range of changing colors most likely includes some that I haven't encountered. So it's hard to achieve the perfect look you want with this setup, not to mention that we're not operating on the same computer but talking through forums.

Comment: Thanks, it indeed works but also color `.` and `,` in red. But I think it is bearable.

Comment: Change the content in the third `scope` to `punctuation.separator,punctuation.section`. [Imgur](https://imgur.com/foq4kyC)

Comment: Glad to help you and wish you a happy life.

Comment: Glad to help you and wish you a happy life.